# Load json data in Android-uitableview

Tags: android, json, uitableview, android-query

**Help please!**

In my application I use `Android-UiTableView` (  [thiagolocatelli / android-uitableview](https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/android-uitableview) ) and `AQuery` (  [androidquery / androidquery](https://github.com/androidquery/androidquery) )

My task is to make the loading of data from json array and load image from URL.
Load a list without pictures I was able to:

```
jgall = json.getJSONArray("gall");                  
int z = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < jgall.length(); i++){
      JSONObject c = jgall.getJSONObject(i);
      tableView.addBasicItem(c.getString("name"), c.getString("place"));
  }
```

I try to show a customized view and nothing happens

```
LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
RelativeLayout view      = (RelativeLayout) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view,null); 
String iurl              = c.getString("img");
aq.id(R.id.img).image(iurl, false, true);                       
ViewItem viewItem        = new ViewItem(view);
tableView.addViewItem(viewItem);
```

Tell me it's real to make using `Android-UiTableView`? if so! how?

Comment: I think you are looking for this: [Android – Asynchronous image loading in ListView](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-asynchronous-image-loading-in-listview/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this by modifying the library code myself.

I have added the following constructor at **UITableView.java**:

```
public void addBasicItem(Drawable drawable, String title, String summary) {
    mItemList.add(new BasicItem(drawable, title, summary));
}
```

And the following at **BasicItem.java**:

```
public Drawable getDDrawable() {
    return dDrawable;
}

public BasicItem(Drawable ddrawable, String _title, String _subtitle) {
    this.dDrawable = ddrawable;
    this.mTitle = _title;
    this.mSubtitle = _subtitle;
}
```

And once again modified the **setupBasicItem** method at **UITableView.java** file:

```
((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image)).setBackgroundDrawable(item.getDDrawable());
```

Finally, at your code add the following:

```
URL newurl = new URL("http://www.example.com/example.png"); 
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(newurl.openConnection() .getInputStream());
Drawable drawable = new android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bmp);

tableView.addBasicItem(drawable, "Title", "SubTitle");
```

Hope it helps, cause it works for me.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Should be obvious, of course, but you also have to add a private Drawable dDrawable to BasicItem.java.